# Sending Files from external application to Salesforce via RESTAPI

Tags: api, rest, file, salesforce

I need to create an API where files ( pdf,png) are pushed from external application to Salesforce.
I tried using Post method to pull files but files are getting created but it's blank when I open it.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried, post some code or example messages?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm - examples for Document and ContentVersion (File).

https://medium.com/@weirdthinker15/uploading-a-document-to-salesforce-using-rest-api-a7481324812a - a blog post if you prefer that over dry documentation. Just remember that all code samples use wrong double quotes (`""`, not `“”`)

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000XuVsQAK - size limitations